# After upgrading Pycharm to 2019 1.1, I cant open any project of old version Pycharm. It just stuck on loading project

Tags: pycharm

After upgrading Pycharm to 2019 1.1, I can't open any project of old version Pycharm. It just stuck on loading project. The only thing I can do is create a new project rather than opening an old one. Now I create new project and open jupyter notebook, it also gets stuck. What's wrong with pycharm or my computer.
[image]

Comment: Please help, does anyone got the same problem

Comment: It's better to contact PyCharm support directly via pycharm-support@jetbrains.com or issue tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY with logs from `C:\Users\$USER\.PyCharm2019.1\system\log`. Meanwhile, as a possible harsh workaround: try to rename `.idea` folder in the project root, it contains per-project settings and will force IDE to recreate defaults. Or rename `C:\Users\$USER\.PyCharm2019.1` it will force PyCharm to recreate per-IDE settings. Close PyCharm before.